# Styling attributes not functioning on merge tags

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, android-styles

**Background**

I have found styling attributes not functioning on the *merge* tags, either apply attributes separately or apply a style.

**Known Solutions**

1. Apply styling attributes on the tag that make use of the layout works. For example, *include* tags and custom tags.
2. Just don't make use of merge.
3. Apply styling programmatically.

However, I am looking for better solutions.

**Why?**

1. It is messy. I have to apply the styling attributes every time I make use of the layout. I make it as an separated layout because they are meant to be reused.
2. I am intentionally using *merge* tag as they have to be the immediate children of the parent layout. For example, the tags are children of a *LinearLayout*. I apply *layout_width="0dp"* and *layout_weight="1"* to have them equally spanning in the parent layout.
3. Reason #2 *plus* the tags are generated programmatically. Thus, I can only apply styling programmatically. It is ugly and extra efforts are needed for maintenance.

**Goal**

Satisfactory workaround(s).

**XML Tags for Illustration Purpose**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CustomStyle">
    <!-- Omitted -->
</merge>
```

*And*

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- Omitted -->
</merge>
```

Both the above tags are not styled.

Answer (score 11):

attributes in a merge tag are ignored. When the XML parser sees a merge tag, it tells it, "Skip this tag and add all of the children directly."

Comment: Use a FrameLayout instead of a merge tag if you want to add attributes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been sitting on this little thingy for a while, so I thought I'll share.

It is quite simple, you specify the layout your are using. It will parse the xml and its attributes, that you then provide to the constructor.

```kotlin
fun Context.defaultAttr(@LayoutRes resource: Int): AttributeSet {
    val parser = resources.getLayout(resource)
    return Xml.asAttributeSet(parser)
}
```

Usage would be something in the lines of this:

```kotlin
class MyCustomView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = context.defaultAttr(R.layout.view_mycustom),
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
        val binding: ViewHabitBinding = ViewMyCustomBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)

        // Your implementation of MyCustom view.
    }
```

I haven't at all looked into the performance of it, but it basically parses the XML and get your attrs out, so I presume it is not completely free. But I'd argue it is trade off to make the view's as clean and readable as possible.